# Is it necessary to have a return in a method to use Junit TDD?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, junit

I have this problem: I need to print the duplicated characters in a String.
Now if you look my code, without return at the end of the loop I will get the algorithm correct. But if I put the char as return the second loop go out before the end.

It's necessary to get a return at the program to be tested?

This is the code:

```
        int[] letters = new int[26];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            letters[s.charAt(i) - 97]++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            if (letters[i] > 1) {
                char c = (char) (i + 97);
                System.out.println(c);
                //return c;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Adding a return there makes your method do the wrong thing.  Therefore, the test will break.

Comment: For proper testability, you should separate the logic (which needs to be tested) from the untestable side-effect (printing).

Comment: You could add the char to an array and return the array at the end. It would keep the method testable and you could print the array which would give the same result

Comment: @SLaks: I know that. The print was only to check if the algorithm works.
The question is, when I start the method I need to return something for the Junit Test?

Comment: So what do you actually want to do with the found chars? store them somewhere? return a list/array? you would need to do one of those to make it testable

Comment: @MaxPringle I put that, but doesn't work:
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
   if (letters[i] > 1) {

    char c = (char) (i + 97);
    char[] copyLoop = new char[26];
    copyLoop[c]++;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code and comments that have been left, here is my suggestion.

```
int[] letters = new int[26];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    letters[s.charAt(i) - 97]++;
}
char[] copyLoop = new char[26];

for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    if (letters[i] > 1) {
        char c = (char) (i + 97);
        copyLoop[i] = c;            
    }
}
return copyLoop;
```

Your comment addressed to myself showed the following...

```
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) 
{ 
    if (letters[i] > 1) 
    { 
        char c = (char) (i + 97); 
        char[] copyLoop = new char[26]; 
        copyLoop[c]++;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that you are declaring a new char array everytime you go into the loop. Declare it outside the loop and add the values to the array. Then return the array.

Based on the comments below to this answer, here is the unit test.

```
@Test public void test1()
{
    char [] result = c.checkDouble("casa"); 
    Assert.assertEquals("a", String.valueOf(result[0]));
}
```

Again I can't stress enough my previous comment

> That one is on you. Set a break point and debug the test. See the value of result and do a manual compare of "al" vs result. Remember, "al" is a string and you are returning an array of chars.

There are a couple things to keep in mind...

1. Set a break point in the test method. Step through the method and stop when it gets to the `Assert` line. Hover over or set a watch to find out the value of result. You can solve this problem easily by doing that.
2. You will find that when you do that `result` is an `array` and you are trying to compare it with a `char`. Now you have a result of `chars` in an array but you will need to access a certain one using an `index` to your array.

Comment: Thank you for your code, but it give me an error on return:
return copyLoop[];
the method is: public char[] checkDouble(String s)

Comment: For future reference, please put the method code in its entirety in the question. Modify it to have the bare minimum. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details. See the updated code in my answer

Comment: why it fails?
`@Test
 public void test1(){
  char [] result = c.checkDouble("wallaby");
  Assert.assertEquals("al", result);
 }`

Comment: That one is on you. Set a break point and debug the test. See the value of result and do a manual compare of "al" vs result. Remember, "al" is a string and you are returning an array of chars.

Comment: `@Test
 public void test1(){
  char [] result = c.checkDouble("casa");
  Assert.assertEquals("a", String.valueOf(result));`
I did that but the test fails and I don't know why!?

Comment: I will struggle myself to find a solution. I am so sorry to bother you, I am learning, thanks.